# Selenium with Vercel

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, vercel

Does anyone have sample code where they successfully ran selenium in Vercel with Python?

I tried running  `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` and all sorts of variations of `browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'./chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)`, but nothing works.

Comment: I don't think you can, you can't install anything on vercel